# Batch script echo or write to 2 files

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file.

```
@if(@a==@b) @end
/* :: batch portion
@ECHO OFF
setlocal 
if exist "%~1" ( 
  cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" < "%~1"
 ) else ( 
  cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" 
 )
 exit /b 
:: JScript portion */ 
while (!WSH.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
 var line=WSH.StdIn.ReadLine();
 var st_token = line.split('\t');
WSH.Echo(st_token[i]);
```

Its echo the token to console and i redirect it to a file. Is it possible to have an additional echo to redirect to a different file?

is it possible to specify a file name to the echo so that If I have to echo the tokens I echoto file A and if its some info, say a log message, i echo to a og file.

I want to be able to log the progress to a log file. I want to be able to do something like. `WSH.echo('a.txt', st_token[i]);`  write tokens to a.txt and `WSH.echo('b.txt', 'Token written successfully');` log message to b.txt. Your option writes tokens to a.txt if a input file was provided OR writes to b.txt if no input was provided. And I want to be able to write to the files alternatively. Something Like `WSH.echo('a.txt', st_token[1]); WSH.echo('b.txt', 'Token 1 written successfully'); WSH.echo('a.txt', st_token[2]); WSH.echo('b.txt', 'Token 2 written successfully');` so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if(@a==@b) @end
/* :: batch portion
@ECHO OFF
setlocal 
if exist "%~1" ( 
  >FILE1.TXT cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" < "%~1"
 ) else ( 
  >FILE2.TXT cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" 
 )
 exit /b 
:: JScript portion */ 
while (!WSH.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
 var line=WSH.StdIn.ReadLine();
 var st_token = line.split('\t');
WSH.Echo(st_token[i]);
```

I believe this should do what you require, batch syntax and language barrier allowing...